# Create database from .mdf file without attaching?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an .mdf file, and I'd like to create a database from it on my computer. But I'd like to create it without attaching it to the .mdf file.

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot "create a database from an .mdf file" - it **IS** the database. It's a SQL Server file, and to use it, you need to attach it to a running SQL Server instance. No way around that....

Comment: Why don't you want to attach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use the MDF as a template, for creating another database, you could simply copy it to a new file and then attach to the copy - but perhaps if you explained what you are trying to accomplish, and why you can't attach to the MDF, you might get better help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create database from your mdf file,please see my example below

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseName] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\...mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\...ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

in case if you dont have the /ldf file : use this

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'pubs',
@physname = 'C:\MSSQL\Data\pubs.mdf'
```

Comment: If you are going to copy something verbatim from technet, please give credit to the source.